# PHP - For Loop Keep Significant Digits

Tags: php, for-loop, formatting

I have a for loop that looks like :

```
for ( $i=00001; $i < 55555; $i++) {
     echo $i;
}
```

I get the following output

1
2
3
4
5
etc.

What I want is :

00001
00002
00003
00004
....
55555

How can I retain the significant digits ?

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes, only their human presentation: use `echo sprint('%05d', $i);` to display

Comment: got it thanks. Here is what I was looking for $formatted_value = sprintf("%05d", $i);